# How to autoload a kernel module in Gentoo Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, gentoo

I want to autoload some kernel modules when it's started. I've read the manual book, but can't help. Now the modules that I want to autoload are `vboxdrv` `vboxnetadp` `vboxpci` `vboxnetflt`, The modules directory is `/lib/modules/3.0.6-gentoo/`, the config file directory is `/etc/modules.autoload.d/kernel-3.0.6`, in this file, the modules are all included. And Now after i reboot it, use `lsmod`, I can't see these modules loaded. What's the the problem?

```
thinkpad walle # ls -l /boot/
总用量 17068
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       1  1月 10 01:22 boot -> .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096  4月 27 10:55 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5771120  3月 23 09:27 kernel-3.0.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5771120  4月 26 17:48 kernel-3.0.6-n5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5876784  4月 27 10:55 kernel-3.0.6-n6
drwx------ 2 root root   16384  1月 17 15:47 lost+found
```

Now I use `kernel-3.0.6-n6` as my boot kernel.

```
thinkpad walle # cat /etc/modules.autoload.d/kernel-3.0.6 
xt_mark
test_nx
scsi_wait_scan
wlagn
ext2
vboxdrv
vboxnetadp
vboxpci
vboxnetflt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/etc/conf.d/modules is not used now. Systemd uses its own structure

Put your module list file in /etc/modules-load.d/
man modules-load.d

Put your module option file in /etc/modprobe.d/
man modprobe.d

Comment: Yes, `/etc/conf.d/modules` is the way to go now. And you can define a list of modules for a specific kernel version like kernel-3.0.6: `modules_3_0_6="vboxdrv vboxnetadp vboxpci vboxnetflt"`.

Answer (score 13):

The autoloaded modules are specified in `/etc/conf.d/modules` according to http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=7#doc_chap5

The `/etc/init.d/modules` script reads the `/etc/conf.d/modules` file and loads the modules. It should already be in the boot runlevel, but if it isn't, run `rc-update add modules boot` to have them loaded on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, editing /etc/conf.d/modules is not autoloading, because you need to edit this file after every kernel rebuild.

The main idea about autoloading **hardware** kernel modules is described here:
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.udev.html
and
http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udev

In few words: udev is managing your hardware, and every time when new hardware appears (kernel creates link in /dev), udev makes search for a proper kernel module, and loads it if found. All the device information is provided by sysfs.